# How to calculate the distances to outlet along the flow path ?

Tags: qgis, distance, saga, flow-map, basin

I have created these raster files for a river basin:

```
DEM
Flow Direction
Flow Accumulation
```

I like to genereate a layer how it is shown in the picture below.
[image]

**I need the values for the distances from each spring to the outlet along the flow path length.**
By now I used Qgis 2.16.1 with Grass and Saga tools.
Moreover I figured out that maybe the r.stream.distance command is what I need, but it isn´t available in the toobox and i couldn´t add it.
I am a newcomer and happy about any explanation.

Comment: It seems a *Flow path length* map to me. In QGIS processng toolbox; GRASS has `r.flow` and SAGA has `Terrain Analysis - Hydrology | Flow path length`